# On window resize Components are also being overlapped

Tags: css

I have my css as shown here

```
body {
    margin:0px auto;
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;  
}
html { overflow-y:scroll; }
a    { color:#038ad8; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer; }   
a:focus { outline: 0; }
a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:#333 }

a.logo, fl, ul#topnav li, ul#topnav li a , .searchBox1, .cmprSite , .chkLbl,
.chk , .selPeriodBox input, .selPeriodBox select, .selPeriodBox label.txtLbl,
 .leftbar, .content, .homeBoxInr1 .homeBox3, .subTabsLinks2 input
{ float: left; }

.fr { float:right; }
h1, h2, h3, ul#topnav, ul#topnav li, form , .subTabs ul, .subTabs  ul
li, .leftNav ul, .leftNav ul li { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

[Please see the image here.](http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=c8638a5)

(I am opening a POPUP WIndow ) a chart is shown with the div.

The issue is that if the window is resized, I don't want my components to be resized.

This is MY Div

```
<div  class="centered" id= "finance"/>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am missing something or don't understand your problem, you need -

```
#finance {width:XXXXpx;}
```

Where XXXX is the size you want your chart to be.